# Get the nested type of a generic CodeProperty using EnvDTE

Tags: visual-studio, envdte

I have a `CodeProperty` object in my T4 template of a generic property (`ICollection<MyNameSpace.MyType>`). How can I get the `CodeElement` object of `MyNameSpace.MyType` so I can inspect and do other things with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may obtain it via `CodeModel.CodeTypeFromFullName("MyNameSpace.MyType")`.

Comment: I wish there was an answer on how you can extract that info dynamically from the `CodeProperty` instance itself...